# can we use azure devops server 2019 or 2020 with sharepoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint, devops

Can we install and use sharepoint 2019 with azure devops server 2019 or 2020?
Is there an integration between both of them or do we use each one separately?

Answer (score 0):

Although you can install Azure DevOps Server on client operating systems, we don't recommend client operating system installation except for evaluation purposes or personal use. Client operating systems have the following restrictions:

Client operating systems don't support integration with SharePoint Products or SharePoint Reporting.
[You can't install Azure DevOps Server Proxy and Team Foundation Server Proxy on client operating systems.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020)
[If you need to use any of these features, install Azure DevOps Server on a server operating system.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020)

Comment: i know that i have to install server operating system...i mean after Can we install and use sharepoint 2019 with azure devops server 2019 or 2020 on windows server? and Is there an integration between both of them or do we use each one separately?

Comment: Sharepoint integration is no longer supported as of TFS 2018 and Azure DevOps Server 2019. Sharepoint 2016 is only supported with a workaround. Sharepoint 2019 is not supported.

Comment: TFS version Supported SharePoint versions
TFS 2018    >>>No longer supported ||
TFS 2017   >>> SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise) 
            SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise) || 
TFS 2015    >>>SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
            SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise) || 
TFS 2013    >>>SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
            SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)

Comment: what is the best to do, install tfs 2017 and sharepoint 2013 to get benefit from sharepoint integration or to install the latest versions which are devops server 2020 and sharepoint 2019 and loose the sharepoint integration?

Comment: It depends on what you want from TFS, but in my opinion, SharePoint is powerful to do anything you want. it's not a big basic difference between 2016 and 2019 SharePoint, major change is added modern mode. it is an appearance change

Comment: is there a big difference between sharepoint 2013 and 2019?? as the sharepoint integration is only between tfs 2017 and sharepoint 2013